# When using collect() on JavaRDD in spark , application becomes slower

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using Apache Spark with spark-Cassandra-connector for data analysis.For that i created a JavaRDD of a table from Cassandra which contains more than 3 million records.

```
JavaRDD<MyTestBean> testRDD = testFunction
            .cassandraTable("keyspace", "table")
            .map(new Function<CassandraRow, MyTestBean>() {

                @Override
                public MyTestBean call(
                        final CassandraRow line) {

                    final MyTestBean beanObj = new MyTestBean();
                    beanObj.setId(line.getString("id")));
                    return beanObj ;
                 }).filter(new Function<MyTestBean , Boolean>() {
                          public Boolean call(MyTestBean s) {
                             long id = s.getId();
                             if (id > 600000) {
                                final_check = true;
                             }
                             return final_check;
                          }
                 });
```

It wont return any rows after the filtering. So when i apply ,

```
testRDD.count();
```

It took approximately 2 minutes to show its count as 0. Is this behavior expected or is there any possible issues from my side?

Comment: I think this behavior is expected. You haven't mentioned the size of your cluster and size of the data. But I think filtering 3 million records may take a while.